# Deploy Scala PlayFramework Project to IBM Bluemix

Tags: java, scala, playframework, ibm-cloud, devops

I've build a RESTFul Service with Play 2.4 Scala2.11, now I want to deploy this to IBM Bluemix.

[play2-war-plugin](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin) was used to package the project to a war package since Bluemix use Liberty as container.

But when I push the war package to Bluemix, I got error logs:

> [ERROR ] SRVE0918E: The attempted blocking write is not allowed because the non-blocking I/O has already been started by the application registering the WriteListener [play.core.server.servlet31.Play2Servlet31RequestHandler$ResultWriteListener@d2487ee8].

I want to knwo:

- Can Scala based PlayFramework project be deployed to IBM Bluemix?
- Are there some better ways to package Play project to a war package?
- In my circumstances, what can I do to confirm whether this ERROR caused by my codes or caused by the [play2-war-plugin](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to package your Play Framework application in a war file in order to deploy it to Bluemix.

Simply build your application using `play dist` or `activator dist` and then use the `java_buildpack` to deploy it. For example:

```
$ cf push play-application -p target/universal/play-application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip -b java_buildpack
```

You can see Java buildpack documentation for Play Framework here:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/example-play_framework.md

Answer (score 2):

Just for people (like me) coming to this page now. Alex de Silva's answer works great but needs some update:

1. Instead of the command `play` or `activator` use `sbt` The `sbt dist` or `sbt stage` command are described [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager). If you use `play` it won't work at all & in the case of `activator`--which is outdated--it will fail with some "can't find dependency" errors. Make sure you have latest version of `sbt` installed.
2. The same instructions apply in *any* sbt-based Scala application, not just Play Framework. You just have to be sure you have the `sbt-native-packager` plugin set up properly in your sbt build.